# Overriding methods on an helper class

Tags: java, android, firebase, overriding, onactivityresult

Ok so Im trying to create a seperate helper class, that would have methods that would be used on many different Activities to avoid repeating code.

I have ran into a problem. Im trying to put in startActivityForResult, which I can do if I pass in the Activity as a parameter to the method. But I dont know how to @Override onActivityResult on this helper class.

Is this even possible to do? If not, how should this be tackled? I dont want to write the same onActivityResult in 10 different Activities.

EDIT: Showing the code in question.

I am using firebase and this is the code I would want repeated onActivityResult

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

            final StorageReference photoRef = mChatPhotosStorageReference.child(selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

            Task<Uri> urlTask = photoRef.putFile(selectedImageUri).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                    if(!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        throw task.getException();
                    } else {
                        return photoRef.getDownloadUrl();
                    }
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                        FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage =
                                new FriendlyMessage(null, mUsername, downloadUri.toString());
                        mMessagesDatabaseReference.push().setValue(friendlyMessage);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

And this is the code for startActivityForResult

```
 mPhotoPickerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), RC_PHOTO_PICKER);
            }
        });
```

Im also planning on using the Firebase AuthUI which would requiere the use of onActivityResult

Comment: Can you please post the code here

Comment: Usually showing some actual code is more helpful than trying to describe it.

Comment: Ok added code to the comment

Comment: Would this be a good candidate for an abstract class?

Comment: Does the helper class extend `Activity` or its derivatives?

Comment: Susmit for some reason I thought that wouldnt work, but I will try.

Comment: I would go down the route of Inheritance based on your description of what you want to achieve - a good place to start looking could be this link to the java docs /tutorials https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: Well I did what Susmit suggested and it actually works, which feels strange for me but thanks :)

Comment: Have you solved the issue?